# the packagist could not be downloaded 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and my composer version is 1.4.1.

I tried to install package `composer require 'name package'` but always failed.

#### Output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin>composer require intervention/image -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file C:/Users/owner/AppData/Roaming/Composer/config.json
Loading config file C:/Users/owner/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\composer-cacert-e62a07e61e5870effa81b430e1900778943c228bd7da1259dd6a955ee2262b47.pem: valid
Executing command (C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD
Executing command (C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin): hg branch
Executing command (C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin): fossil branch list
Executing command (C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin): fossil tag list
Executing command (C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin): svn info --xml
Reading C:/Users/owner/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Loading config file C:/Users/owner/AppData/Roaming/Composer/config.json
Loading config file C:/Users/owner/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json
Loading config file C:/Users/owner/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Loading config file C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\Composer/auth.json
Reading C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\Composer/auth.json
Reading C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin/vendor/composer/installed.json
Reading C:/Users/owner/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Running 1.4.1 (2017-03-10 09:29:45) with PHP 5.6.12 on Windows NT / 10.0
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-2015%24c825dba6ea97350c3a10e76223062d4cba03d75a1d4383b5d05ba69fb5185f04.json
                                       Writing C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-2016-04%243c63bda82e7264704dfb6ea97ca8ebb7a8f2e6fd44760f91fdc07d97e903a674.json
Writing C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016-04.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016-07.json from cache
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-2016-10%24145b9d3fe5c71b37120568e1af00aef894ac7def81190d575b9a3bb47e80b31d.json
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-2016-10%24145b9d3fe5c71b37120568e1af00aef894ac7def81190d575b9a3bb47e80b31d.json


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/p/provider-2016-10%24145b9d3fe5c71b37120568e1af00aef894ac7def81190d575b9a3bb47e80b31d.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)


Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:365
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->get() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:101
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getContents() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:661
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->fetchFile() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:573
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->loadProviderListings() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:296
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->whatProvides() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:204
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->computeWhatProvides() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:193
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->whatProvides() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionSelector.php:52
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionSelector->findBestCandidate() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php:634
 Composer\Command\InitCommand->findBestVersionForPackage() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php:365
 Composer\Command\InitCommand->determineRequirements() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:117
 Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:267
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:846
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:227
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:122
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:100
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:54
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:24

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...


C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin>
```

I checked my composer using `composer diagnose` and I think there's nothing wrong:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\dhuha_service_admin>composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

I tried to install `laravelcollective/html` too and the result is same.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

[UPDATE]
when i tried to install again the error now change to `content-length mismatch` (i don't know why, sometimes i got error 'failed to open stream http' but mostly i get content-length error).  i have tried to add

```
"repositories": [
    {
         "type": "composer", 
         "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    { "packagist": false }
]
```

but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Though I'm not expert of this but I have searched something.
Try executing the following commands :

- Clear composer cache

  composer clear-cache
- Update composer

  composer self-update
- Execute these two commands

  composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
  composer config -g github-protocols https ssh

If it didn't work try these :

- Clear composer cache

  composer clear-cache
- Update composer (Can be avoided 2nd time)

  composer self-update

It seems that there are some network issues from time to time on the main server **https://packagist.org**. then use mirrors as a temporary workaround. Execute the following command :

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https?://packagist.jp
```

(It'sslow, but might work.)

References : 
**https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7021**